# How to create connection to database

Tags: c#

This is my code:

```cs
string dbInfo;
SqlConnection dbConnection;
public Sales_Database()
{
    dbInfo = @"SERVER=185.175.200.35;DATABASE=guusbxg438_products;UID=*****;PASSWORD=******";

}
public override bool Connect()
{
     dbConnection = new SqlConnection(dbInfo);
     dbConnection.Open();
}
```

This is the upfollowing exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "A network error or an instance-specific error occurred while connecting to SQL Server. The server was not found or is not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that the SQL Server settings allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open connection to SQL Server) '

Comment: According to the error message the server (185.175.200.35) is currently not available. Are the ports open ?

Comment: What database are you trying to connect to? The Sql* classes are specific to SqlServer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to connect to an SQL or MySQL database. At the moment you are connecting to an SQL server. Since you have the tag phpmyadmin, it will probably a MySQL database. Therefor you need a MySQL connector.

Read more here: http://zetcode.com/csharp/mysql/

Example from source above:

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace Version
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string cs = @"server=localhost;userid=dbuser;password=s$cret;database=testdb";

            using var con = new MySqlConnection(cs);
            con.Open();

            Console.WriteLine($"MySQL version : {con.ServerVersion}");
        }
    }
}
```